# C program that only performs when there's an input redirection

Tags: c, redirect, stdin

I'm a C newbie and I need some help.  So this is the problem I'm having with the terminal.  Let's say I'm inputting a text file.

```
./Terminal < someFile.txt
```

How do I get my program to only perform a duty when a file has been input,  else do another task?

```
int main() {
     //If user input is a file, do something
     if()
          //do something
     else
          //do something else
            
}
```

Sorry if I'm not formulating my question correctly, beginner programmer here.

Comment: Are you required to use input redirection? Could you pass the file name as an argument instead?

Comment: You probably need to look at [`fstat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstat.html) or [`isatty()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isatty.html).  The former can be used to find out the type of file for a given file descriptor (`STDIN_FILENO` or `0` for standard input); the latter can tell you whether the standard input is a terminal (and, if it isn't, you can probably assume that the input comes from a pipe or file).

Comment: The above comment is the answer, however, another option is to only accept input from a file. In the past `-` was a special case to signify stdin.  On Linux you can use  `/dev/stdin` so you don't need the special case.

Comment: @hardStuckProgrammer, What should happen with only `./Terminal`?  (no arguments)

Comment: @ chux - Reinstate Monica it'll just return ```./Terminal``` until the user put a proper command

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a program's stdin is connected to a terminal using [`isatty(0)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isatty.html).

Answer (score -1):

It is standard for linux processes to read standard input, and write to standard output, unless given arguments to tell them to do otherwise.  This enables pipelines, which are powerful.

If you want to know whether a file has been piped or redirected in, that will be a challenge.  I recommend instead to use command-line arguments to allow the user to tell you which operation they want performed.

The `getopt` function is very helpful for this purpose.